# Partial specialization on a templated template parameter

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a trait class test that detects whether a specific class (let's call it `A`) occurs in a nested template type. A positive example would be `B<C<A<int>>>` (`A` makes occurrence). I succeed but I need to add partial specializations for all classes that are not `A`. Is there a nicer way? Can use any C++ standard.

```
#include<cassert>

template<class T> class A;
template<class T> class B;
template<class T> class C;
template<class T> class D;


// class template
template<class T> struct test_for_A;


// specialization for A
template<class T> struct test_for_A< A<T> >
{
  constexpr static bool value = true;;
};


// specializations for all other classes
template<class T> struct test_for_A< B<T> >
{
  constexpr static bool value = test_for_A<T>::value;
};



// Instead of repeating this partial specialization for each
// class that is not A, I was hoping to do something like the following.
// Doesn't work as T is not a template.
template<class T, class T1>
struct test_for_A< T<T1> >
{
  constexpr static bool value = test_for_A<T1>::value;
};



int main()
{
  assert( test_for_A< B<A<B<int> > > >::value );
}
```

Comment: `A` is not a class. It is a template, or more specifically a class template. What you want is not currently possible in general. You need to make some additional assumptions, in particular whether or not `A`'s template parameters are guaranteed to be of specific kinds, i.e. is only `template<class T> class A;` allowed or also e.g. `template<auto T> class A;`, etc? The same assumptions must be made about the kinds of template parameters of `B`, `C`, etc. as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a template-template parameter:

```cpp
template<template<class> class T, class T1>
struct test_for_A< T<T1> >
{
  constexpr static bool value = test_for_A<T1>::value;
};
```

Comment: Could I specialize that with: `template<template<class> class T>
struct test_for_A<T<bool>> { ...};`